# convert a datevalue returned from object to DD-MM-YYYY format

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert the "20150812" to "12-08-2015".
my returned date object shown below:

```
study response = [
{
    "dob": {
        "Value": [
            "20151208"
        ]
    }
} 
]
```

javascript function
  `var dob = study["dob"]["Value"]; //returning 20151208`

expected output
//08-12-2015

tried the following :
`Date.parse(dob) ; //return NaN`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the code snippet correct? `study["dob"]["Value"]` should not return `20151208` from the code that you have.

Comment: yes it is correct. i checked by console log

Comment: did this and works  too :                       var year = String(dob).substr(0, 4);
                      var month = String(dob).substr(4, 2);
                      var day = String(dob).substr(6, 2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to convert the "20150812" to "12-08-2015"

Since `dob` is a text string, and you want a text string result, this is probably easiest to do with text string manipulation, like this:

```
// var dob = study["dob"]["Value"]; //returning 20151208
var dob = "20151208";
var converted = dob.replace(/^(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$/, "$2-$3-$1");
console.log(converted);
```

The output will match your expected output.

Comment: Can also simplify with `/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment js to manipulate dates. Read more : [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)
below code converts your string date which is in format `YYYYDDMM` to `DD-MM-YYYY`

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>

<script>
   var mydate = 20151208;
   var str  = moment(20151208,"YYYYDDMM").format('DD-MM-YYYY');//You need this line
  console.log(str);
</script>
```

You can also use take substrings to get day,month and year

```js
var str = "20151208";
var year = str.substr(0, 4);
var day = str.substr(4, 2);
var month= str.substr(6,2);
console.log( day+"-"+month+"-"+year);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.